# svn: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined symbol: ber_sockbuf_io_udp on redhat

Tags: svn, symbols, lookup, rhel8

Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2 (Ootpa)

Our linux admins installed subversion - not sure which version- assuming latest.

When running svn (just typed svn nothing else), I get the following error:

```
svn: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined symbol: ber_sockbuf_io_udp
```

Why is this? How can it be resolved?

I am a linux user not an admin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

similar thread here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193320/yum-corrupted-on-rhel-6

In my case (RHEL7.8 + Apache 2.4 + Shibboleth 3.2) I was able to resolve the issue by replacing the `/usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2` library with the one from the Apache directory: `<APACHE_ROOT>/HTTPServer/openldap/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2`

Run:
`locate libldap_r-2.4.so.2`
to find the location of the library.
In my case I got:

```
/app/ptc/Windchill_12.0/HTTPServer/openldap/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
/app/ptc/Windchill_12.0/HTTPServer/openldap/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.12
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7
/usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
/usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7
```

I noticed that the lib used in the error was in `/usr/lib64` dir.
I replaced it and now `./apachectl -t` reports
"Syntax OK"

I don't know enough about Linux to explain what is going on here or what the correct fix is.
This was my observation and resolved the issue, I believe my steps are a hack though.

Anyone with a more elegant, upgrade proof solution?

Reference: https://groups.google.com/g/repmgr/c/TS7QfYEoNoY

```
cd /usr/lib64/
ll | grep libldap
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       21 Feb 11 16:42 libldap-2.4.so.2 -> libldap-2.4.so.2.10.7
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   352512 Jun  6  2020 libldap-2.4.so.2.10.7
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       23 Feb 11 16:42 libldap_r-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   381328 Jun  6  2020 libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7
```

It does seem like `/usr/lib64/libldap_r2.4.so.2` is just a symlink to `libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7`.

I wonder if there are missing or deprecated symbols in 2.10.7...
Is there any way to tell the diff in the 2 versions?

**UPDATE**
I noticed that you can make use of the `LoadFile` command in the Apache conf.
Adding `LoadFile <APACHE_ROOT>/HTTPServer/openldap/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2` in my 00-shib.conf file before the `LoadModule mod_shib /usr/lib64/shibboleth/mod_shib_24.so` entry resolved the issue.

This still seems like a workaround / hack to me and there may be an underlying issue with the libraries / different versions.